# How can i implement this data structure?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

Does anyone have an idea about the idea of implementing a data structure so that - the following things will happen?

The structure should save the amount of money that n people have, each person has for example a "cell" that contains the amount of money he has.

And then, how can you implement this data structure so that for example you can implement the ***getMostM(m)*** function - which returns the names of the m people with the most money (sorted in descending order).
***Complexity for this function: Time: O(m)***
***Complexity of Location: O (n)***

There are a total of $n$ people.

Comment: What are all the operations you want to perform on the data structure?  Do you want to be able to insert additional people?  Change the amount of money a person has?  Do you care about their running time?  What does "Location" refer to?  What data structures have you already considered?  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Hint:  [Heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) are used for storing things in a "sorted" manner. Do note though that since your question doesn't put any limitations on insertion complexity, you could as well just store things in an array and sort every time you insert giving you exactly O(m) access time.